# Bot Framework Facebook Messenger bug with simultaneous conversation

Tags: c#, facebook, botframework, messenger, azure-language-understanding

We use the Microsoft Bot Framework and we have a bug when we talk to our bot on Facebook Messenger: If two different people ask something at the same time, one of the users receives both answers and the other doesn't receive anything.

We use Luis for machine learning and our bot is built in C#.

Have you got an idea about this problem?

Comment: How about showing use some codes... Currently it sounds like an intresting problem, but we can't help you.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!

We has a static message into our ClassDialog (which use Luis) as a variable. Just delete the "Static" and it works! :D

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED!

We had a static acitivity in our ClassDialog (which uses Luis) as a variable. Just delete the "Static" and it works!